# CSS Info box rollover

Tags: css, image, rollover

I'm trying to create a simple rollover with an image to show a tip or info box/bubble.
I have a div wrapper holding the image src, and css to style/position the wrapper and child.
I just can't figure out how to make the img src interactive.
Here's the html:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/gallery/wheat3.png" width="250" height="250" data-stellar-ratio="3.5" data-stellar-vertical-offset="200">
    </div>
```

I want to create a rollover with the image "wheat3.png" to show and info box at the side.

Here's the test link as well:
http://hatfielddesign.com/witbier_test/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the source code of the test link you've shown, seems like they uses [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) to implement this effect. Take a read at the [docs](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/docs/), they may help you ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Steller.js for the parallax effect.